# Bumblee PPA failed to fetch on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, ppa, bumblebee

When I attempt an update, I can't pull down the bumblebee ppa for saucy.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages      404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Even after following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) to a tee. I can't seem to find the ppa directory in any documentation to cross check. I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with an nvidia GeForce GT 750M.

Comment: Got it, forgot the first rule of computers, always restart first.

Comment: @user198568: Does your comment about restarting the computer mean it's now fixed.